# How to start pursuing a written conversation after a while?

Tags: communication, email

I've communicated with an office for a while about a request. After a few weeks I want to pursue this conversation by asking more information. I'm communicating via E-mail. I'm not sure how rather formal emails in this situation start. Is it a good idea to use follow up phrase? For example,

```
Dear ...

Following up my request, I talked with Mr X and received a response. Can 
you ...(The sentence continues)

Thank you
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general question on email writing style and has nothing to do with the workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few weeks is not an overly long delay. If in doubt, I'd make sure to reply to the same thread rather than sending a new email, so your recepient has a chance to refresh their memory.

Your relationship is significant: are they a supplier to whom you are a customer? In this case you don't need to be overly polite, they're keeping customer records and it's part of their job to 'recollect' past conversations.

If the relationship's more balanced, or if the recipient is in power (ie. they're the customer), it might be courteous to start with a brief sentence on where you left things off:

> A few weeks ago we discussed X and Y.

Some recruiters send me cutesy messages starting with *Do you remember me?* but they're aiming for Silicon Valley-style directness and informality. Again, depends on your relationship with the recipient.

You didn't specify locale, if you're both in the same culture, then cultural norms must also be observed (obviously), whatever they may be. Otherwise, your template looks perfectly fine.